# How do I regex htaccess for my search query

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Example my URL

`http://domain.com/search.php?s=search&w=state&t=town&c=category&p=1`

- s = search keyword
- w = region
- t = town
- c = category
- p = paging

What I have done for now in my `.htaccess` is

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /search.php?s=$1&w=$2&t=$3&c=$4&p=$5 [L]
```

And the URL will be

`http://domain.com/search/keyword/region/town/category/1/`

Question

How do I rewrite my .htaccess to make my URL can be global query.

Example `s=bmw+5+series&w=&t=&c=`

`http://domain.com/search/bmw-5-siries/`

Example `s=bmw+5+series&w=&t=&c=car`

`http://domain.com/search/car/bmw-5-siries/`

Example `s=bmw+5+series&w=manchester&t=&c=car`

`http://domain.com/search/manchester/car/bmw-5-siries/`

or other output as long in the queries term.`

This is possible?

Comment: How would the .htaccess rule be able to differentiate between http://domain.com/keyword/ and http://domain.com/town/ - or do you literally mean to use "keyword" and "town" in the URL?

Comment: @eapen - Actually `search.php` already did the work. Which `empty` or `!isset` for each `$_GET` then return the result according to my need.

Comment: @eapen - Sorry added `/search/`

Comment: You need to add individual rules for each condition you want to handle. But this assumes that the length (number of slashes) will remain consistent for each type of query. 

i.e. 4 slashes means the region, category and keywords will be in the URL and 3 slashes means it will only have category and the keywords and 2 slashes means it will only have the keywords.

Comment: Yeah, double slashs will be there and can remove it by `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$ RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest method would be to edit the SEO URLs to prepend the search term with a character to identify the searched term.

i.e.

/search/bmw-5-series/r/Manchester/c/Car
or
/search/bmw-5-series/c/Luxury

and use the variables along with a RewriteCond to identify which RewriteRule to apply.

With your current method, it would be hard to identify if the third item (eg. car) is a town or the category or something else, unless you have fixed rules. (i.e If Town is passed then the Region will definitely be passed so you can write a different set of rules to handle each condition instead of the single rule you have now)

eg.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /search.php?s=$1&w=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)//$ /search.php?s=$1&w=$2&t=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /search.php?s=$1&w=$2&t=$3&c=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /search.php?s=$1&w=$2&t=$3&c=$4&p=$5 [L]
```

Comment: Sound like that. need to have individual rules. Thanks eapen :)

Comment: Thnx and I love your username.